# Page can't access my cookies through GET or POST requests

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm trying to send a request from `admin.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com/api` but `mydomain.com/api` can't access my cookies.

I've tried setting the domain on all cookies to `.mydomain.com` so all subdomains can access the cookie, but this did nothing.

I made `mydomain.com/api` return `dd($_COOKIE)`. After doing this the response was `[]` (which shows that the page can't access cookies), but when I go to the page in my browser I am able to see all the cookie information, so it's something related to the subdomain and the request.

`mydomain.com/api` response code:

```
public function api(Request $request){
    return dd($_COOKIE);
    . . .
```

The request:
[image]

The response:
[image]

When I go to the page in my browser:
[image]

I should be able to send requests to the API and it should see that I am authenticated, however, the API is not able to read my cookies so it can't see that I'm an admin user so I can't perform any actions.

Comment: Postman doesn't share cookies with your browser. It's separate. Your `[]` doesn't show it can't access cookies, it shows there *aren't* any cookies. You need to include your cookie in your Postman request.

Comment: There are cookies though. I have a `session` cookie that uses the `.mydomain.com` domain.

Comment: Are you including that cookie in the Postman requests?

Comment: I don't use Postman.

Comment: Still not fixed this... anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Still got this problem

Answer (score 0):

here you go

## .env file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mcv2.mobi
```

```
File path: /app/Http/Middleware

class EncryptCookies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'test_cookie'
    ];
}
```

Setting Cookies

```
Route::get('set_cookie', function(){

    $response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response();
    $response->withCookie(cookie('test_cookie', 'my value', 60));
    dd(request()->cookie());
});
```

Retrieving Cookies

```
Route::any('get_cookie', function (){
    dd(request()->cookie());
});
```

Check the attachments
[subdomain1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcpTA.png)
[subdomain2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXYnE.png)

Comment: This would mean having to change all code that I have though. I've already got 50+ pages on the site. Is there not a way to do it with `setcookie()` and `$_COOKIE`?  It looks like it's just an issue with the domain not being allowed to take cookies from the subdomain.